# Is dynamodb suitable for growing or pivotable product?

Tags: amazon-web-services, nosql, amazon-dynamodb

Amazon said

> NoSQL design requires a different mindset than RDBMS design. For an RDBMS, you can create a normalized data model without thinking about access patterns. You can then extend it later when new questions and query requirements arise. For DynamoDB, by contrast, you shouldn't start designing your schema until you know the questions it needs to answer. Understanding the business problems and the application use cases up front is absolutely essential.

It seems that I should design the tables after designing the product for efficient query cost.

But a product can be pivoted or be appended new features. In early stage, nobody knows where the product goes.

Is dynamodb suitable for growing or pivotable product?

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, the main benefit of Dynamo DB over other NoSQL solutions is that it is a managed database service. You pay for reads and writes and you never worry about scaling to handle larger data, more users. If you are doing a prototype or don't have technical know-how to setup a database server and host in the cloud it could be useful and cost effective. It has its limitations however so if you do have technical resources consider another open source NoSQL option.

I think that statement by Amazon is confusing and is probably more marketing than anything else. Use NoSQL in cases where your data is only accessed in distinct elements that do no have to be combined in a complex manner. It's also helpful if you don't have an exact schema defined because NoSQL doesn't require a hard set schema you can store any fields in a table and you can always add new fields. This is helpful when things are changing rapidly and you don't want to migrate everything as strictly as an RDBMS would require. If however you're going to have to run complex logic or calculations combining data from across tables you should use an RDBMS. You could use NoSQL for some data and and RDBMS for other data in a hybrid fashion but in that case you probably wouldn't want to use Dynamo DB because you'd want full ownership to set it up properly. Hope this helps I'm sure others have more to say and I welcome comments to help me refine my answer.

Comment: +1 for @spakmad's answer. In other words, that excerpt is Amazon's disclaimer that you will not be able to run the ad-hoc declarative queries many are used to in the RDBMS world.

That being said, I _do_ think Dynamo is a good choice when starting a project because it is (1) pay as you go, (2) a managed service, and (3) integrates very well with AWS's other managed services.